# The set of $z\in \partial\mathbb{D} $ such that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {z^{2^n}} $ diverges is dense in $\mathbb{D}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Let  $\mathbb{D} = \{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$ and $\partial\mathbb{D} = \{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|=1\}$

Show that the set of $z \in \partial \mathbb{D} $ such that the series diverges is dense in $\partial \mathbb{D}$

**My attempt**

Let $z = e^{ix} \in \partial \mathbb{D}$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

We have:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty {z^{2^n}}  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {e^{ix}}^{2^n}=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty {e^{2^nix}}
$$

Since $|e^{2^nix}| = 1$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Thus the series diverges $\forall z \in \partial \mathbb{D}$.

Am I right?

Comment: You are so much right that I *suspect* that the problem wanted to ask something less trivial. Perhaps "diverges to infinity" instead of "diverges"? (Still trivial)

Comment: $\{e^{2i \pi n / 2^k}\}$ is dense in the unit circle

Comment: The "$\mathbb D$" at the end of the title of the question must be changed by "$\partial\mathbb D$".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is unclear. $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n}$ is analytic on $|z| < 1$. We want to know if it can be analytically continued on a larger domain.

If $z = r e^{2i \pi m / 2^k}$ then $z^{2^k} = r^{2^k}$ so that $$f(r e^{2i \pi m / 2^k}) = \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} z^{2^n} + \sum_{n=k}^\infty r^{2^k} = \mathcal{O}(k)+\sum_{n=k}^\infty r^{2^k}$$
thus $$\lim_{r \to 1^-} f(r e^{2i \pi m / 2^k}) = \lim_{r \to 1^-}\sum_{n=k}^\infty r^{2^k}= +\infty$$
Therefore $f(z)$ isn't continuous at $z = e^{2i \pi m / 2^k}$.

But $\{e^{2i \pi m / 2^k}, (m,k) \in \mathbb{N}^2\}$ is dense in the unit circle,  and hence $f(z)$ isn't continuous anywhere on $|z|=1$, which means it can't be analytically continued beyond the unit disk.

This is a typical example of a natural boundary of the domain of an analytic function.

Comment: +1, your answers are very good. I believe that there are typos when you write $\sum_{n=k}^\infty r^{2^k} $, should be $\sum_{n=k}^\infty r^{2^n} $.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g$ be your powerseries. Note that $|g(z^{2^n})| \leqslant |g(z)|+n$, and then prove that $\lim |g(t)| = 1$ as $t$ increases to $1$. Now prove that if $\zeta^{2^n}=1$, then $\lim |g(t\zeta)| =\infty$ as $t$ increases to $1$ using the two facts above. This proves the set of $2^n$th roots of unity is contained in the set of boundary points where $g$ diverges, and this is a dense subset of the boundary.